# Sorting Float Column vs Int Column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

I wonder if type of a column matters in terms of sorting performance. I have heard that `int` columns are sorted faster than `float` columns. Do you think it is correct?

Comment: If you have all integer data, it is foolish to define it as a float in any case. Float is an inexact data type and should be avoided as much as possible. You don;t really want your value of 10 to be stored as 10.00000001 or something silly do you? You can have severe rounding errors when using float. Do not use it if you intend to do math calculations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For columns without an index on them, sorting does depend on the data type.

Floats are more complex than integers, so it is logical to conclude that sorting them takes a bit longer.

Comment: Adding to that, floats take more storage space, so the index for floats should take more space thus being slower than indexes for ints.